# UINavigationController in SWRevealViewController's frontViewController goes back to root VC when dismissing a presented VC?

Tags: ios, swrevealviewcontroller

I'm having some trouble using `UIImagePickerController` together with `SWRevealViewController`.

In my `SWRevealViewController`, my `frontViewController` is a navigation controller. In this navigation controller, I have 2 VCs (call them VC1 and VC2) in the navigation stack. From the topmost VC (VC2), I show a `UIImagePickerController` using `presentViewController:animated:completion:`, with VC2 itself as the delegate. When the user has picked an image, the `imagePickerController:didFinishPickingMediaWithInfo:` delegate method is called, I do stuff with the image picked, and then I call `dismissViewController:animated:` to dismiss the image picker. However, **instead of just going back to VC2, the app goes all the way back to VC1 (i.e. the root view controller of the navigation controller)**.

After some testing, it seems like the problem isn't specific to using `UIImagePickerController`, but with presenting any VC using `presentViewController:animated:completion:` from inside the front VC. I experimented by presenting just a dummy VC instead of the image picker controller, and the same problem happens - when the presented VC is dismissed, the nav controller goes back to the root VC instead of staying at the presenting VC.

I need to use `UIImagePickerController` in the app - how can I get around the problem above?

- I can't push a `UIImagePickerController` onto the navigation controller
- I would not want to recreate the functionality of `UIImagePickerController`

Help appreciated!

Answer (score 0):

Aargh, silliness...

I'm subclassing SWRevealViewController, and had put the code that loads and sets the front view controller in the SWRevealViewController's `viewWillAppear`, so every time the image picker is dismissed and the SWRevealViewController reappears, it re-sets its front view controller. Putting the code in `viewDidLoad` solved the problem. :/